# Android Studio signed app won't install on device - "Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've been trying to solve this problem for about 5 days.
I've created an app for my work place in Android Studio, and it works fine when I run it in debug mode with the ADB. But when I generate the signed apk and try to install it on my device (Samsung Galaxy S6, Marshmallow 6.0.1) it always shows "Unfortunatelly, Package installer has stopped".

I have already changed the Build Variant to "release", and checked the password for the key store several times, also uninstalled the previous app and looked for remaining data like in other questions tell you to fix this problem. I think the problem is not there.

This code is in my build.grade :
[Code Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrOXv.jpg)

I've tried the same with other apps I have created along with the Udacity Beginners Course (I'm kind of new in Android developing) and they work just fine when I create and install the signed .apk.

Also, I noticed that inside my phone there are folders of every app installed, inside Android -> data; here I can find the folders for the apps form the Beginners Course, but even if I run the one I'm developing with the ADB, the folder doesn't appear. Is this normal?

Hope someone can help me!

- EDIT -

I think I found the problem with your help, but I still don't know how to fix it. This is what appears in the Android Monitor. 
[Android Monitor Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G5KU.jpg)

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: first you need to find error. to do that   install your app while   your mobile connected to your pc ( or mac )  before install  open android studio. select  no filter on android  monitor.  when your app fail to install . find the error from log  & post it here

Comment: Try the release build with a debug signing config. If you can install it, there's a problem with your release signing config.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I've already tried to intal the app with a debug signing config, but it still gets me the same message. Now I'm trying the one App Bird told me, but how do I regonize the error? I'm installing the apk with the Android Monitor open.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't around for some days. In the main thread, I added what I did and the error that the Android Monitor shows me, hope you know how to fix this. Thanks!